# How to make Opera stop asking to be my default browser?

Tags: opera

Every time I start Opera it asks if I want it to be my default browser. Today I clicked "yes" on accident, then had to go fix it. How do I stop it? A google search says there is a "check if Opera is default browser on startup" option, but that is an old answer and the settings page no longer looks like that.

Windows 7, Opera version 54.0.2952.64, which is current.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open the URL `opera://flags/#set-as-default-browser` in the browser to access *"Set as default browser on the Speed Dial page"* setting in the *Experiments* section and set it to *Disabled* to (hopefully) get rid of it.

Comment: The popup I'm referring to isn't on the Speed Dial page, but on the page that opens when I start the browser. I did try setting that setting, but it had no effect (possibly because my home page isn't the Speed Dial page).

Comment: OK, thanks for the heads up. Actually I cannot reproduce the problem.  I've installed Opera but it never asked me that question yet for some reason.

Comment: That's interesting, because when I installed it, it made itself my default browser without even asking.